# Devolver atributos de HttpServletRequest con RequestContextHolder

Tags: java, optimización

Estoy trabajando con JWT y es necesario manejar los *claims* desde una clase, para esto cree la siguiente `AuthContextHolder.java`:

```
package com.payulatam.ppp4.secure.api.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import com.payulatam.ppp4.secure.api.model.commons.SecureApiResources;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;

public class AuthContextHolder {

    public Integer getWebUserId(){
        return getIntegerClaims(SecureApiResources.WEB_USER_ID_PARAM);
    }

    public Integer getMerchantId(){
        return getIntegerClaims(SecureApiResources.MERCHANT_ID_PARAM);
    }

    public Integer getDefaultAccountId(){
        return getIntegerClaims(SecureApiResources.DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID_PARAM);
    }

    public Integer getIntegerClaims(String claimParameter){
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        final Claims claims = (Claims) request.getAttribute(SecureApiResources.CLAIMS_ATTR);
        return (Integer) claims.get(claimParameter);
    }

}
```

Perso me surge la duda de si esta clase puede mejorarse a través del uso de un patrón o con un enfoque distinto.

A continuación muestro un ejemplo de la implementación de esta clase:

```
private AuthContextHolder authContextHolder = new AuthContextHolder();

@RequestMapping(value = SecureApiResources.Asobancaria.URL_ASOBANCARIA_MERCHANT_ACCOUNTS, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

public @ResponseBody List<AccountAsobancariaBank> getAccountsAsobancaria() throws Exception {

    List<AccountAsobancariaBank> asobancariaData = asobancariaService.getAccounts(authContextHolder.getMerchantId());

    if ((asobancariaData.get(0) == null)) {
        HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(
        SecureApiResources.ERROR_ACCOUNTS_NOT_FOUND);
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(httpErrors);
    }

    return asobancariaData;
}
```

Agradezco sus consejos.

Comment: No encuentro ningún problema con lo que muestras. ¿Qué clase de optimización buscas? Ojo que la optimización prematura no siempre es bueno.

Comment: Por ejemplo no sé si es mejor crear en este caso atributos privados en `AuthContextHolder` como `private webUserId` y se utilicen los metodos como getters publicos. Si está bien que esta sea una clase simple.

Comment: En mi opinión, lo mejor es trabajar lo más stateless posible. Solo mantén estado si es estrictamente necesario p.e. DTOs. Si tu clase `AuthContextHolder` necesita ser creada/recreada por request, entonces no es relevante que mantenga estado. Por último, solo realiza la optimización que indicas si puedes demostrar que el método `getIntegerClaims` realmente es un cuello de botella en la aplicación vía micro benchmarks o vía ejecutar la aplicación y colocar un profiler para medir el rendimiento del método bajo situaciones de estrés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comentan no veo nada malo en tu código pero si quieres ver otro enfoque te adjunto mi versión de tu clase, reduzco el numero de métodos y reduzco la visibilidad del método getIntegerClaims, y creo un tipo enum para los nombre de los parametros, de la siguiente forma:

```
public class AutoContextHolder {
  public static Integer get(Params paramName) {
    return getIntegerClaims(paramName.getValue());
  }

  private static Integer getIntegerClaims(String claimParameter) {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    final Claims claims = (Claims) request.getAttribute(SecureApiResources.CLAIMS_ATTR);
    return (Integer) claims.get(claimParameter);
  }

  public enum Params {
    WEB_USER_ID(SecureApiResources.WEB_USER_ID_PARAM),
    MERCHANT_ID(SecureApiResources.MERCHANT_ID_PARAM),
    DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID(SecureApiResources.DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID_PARAM);

    Params(String paramName) {
      this.paramName=paramName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return paramName;
    }

    private String paramName;
  }

}
```

Al usar el código quedaria así:

```
List<AccountAsobancariaBank> asobancariaData =asobancariaService.getAccounts(AutoContextHolder.get(Params.MERCHANT_ID));
```

Como te decia es otro punto de vista.